# Visual indication of last view chat message

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

Some type of visual indication of the last viewed message would be nice, seeing that you are keeping track of that.

This was mentioned in the chat, and people seemed to be in favor of it there.  Figured it should be here too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a dotted line indicating where we *think* you last read to in chat.